# virtual host not working in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, virtual, host

I'm working on an Ubuntu 16.04 server with Apache and I'm trying to setup 2 virtual host in the local server(192.168.50.200) . The problem is I don't know how to setup the .conf files correctly. i have created two configuration file in the site_available folder, enabled both configuration file using *a2ensite* command. And the below IP and URL included in the *etc/host* file

*192.168.50.200  test.site1.com*

*192.168.50.200  test.site2.com*

**site1.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.site1.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**site2.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2.com
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

these configuration links are available in the site_enabled folder.

After these configuration i restrated the apache server and also try to reboot the server but no luck.